# How to set the id to each new array in an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have array of objects like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "password": "qwe"
    },
    {
        "name": "qwe1",
        "password": "qwe1"
    }
]
```

I need add `id` each pair of "name" and "password", it must be like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "password": "qwe"
        "id":"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "qwe1",
        "password": "qwe1"
        "id":"1"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to move an array using `foreach`

```
$users[] = array('name' => $name, 'password' => $password);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($users as $key => $value, "id" => 0) {
        $value['id'] = $i;
        $i++;
}
```

I'm beginner in php, help please.What i do wrong?

Comment: Whats the key now? print_r($users);

Comment: What's up with the `, "id" => 0` inside your foreach-expression?

Comment: `$i = 0;
foreach($users){
  $users[$user] = "id" => $i;
  $i++;
}`

Comment: just add the attribute

Comment: @clearshot66 Where does the variable `$user` come from? And your example have some serious syntax errors.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the user's array $users[] =....,  he didn't state what the original array's name was so I just used that as an example

Comment: @clearshot66 Sure he did. `$users`. But then you threw in `$user` (which is not defined) with a few syntax errors (like just passing one array to foreach and `= "id" => $i;`)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ignore, sore, that was meant to be ['user'] as to set up a key'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through an array using: `foreach($array as $key => $value)`, the `$value` will be a *copy* of the original object. Changing the copy will have no effect on the original array.

You need to make sure you update the original value. There are two ways you can do this.

**Accessing the original array directly:**

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    // Access the original array directly
    $users[$key]['id'] = $i;
    $i++;
}
```

**Using references** (The `&`-sign):

```
foreach ($users as $key => &$value) {
    // The & will make it a reference to the original value instead of a copy
    $value['id'] = $i;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thx you very much!